# How to extract a string from a json file and put into a variable (Linux)

Tags: command-line, text-processing, json

I have the following in one of my json file file1.json :-

```json
{
  "$quer": {
    "args": [{
      "args": [
        "select\n      db1.table1 as tab1,\n      db1.table2 as tab2,\n      db1.table3 as tab3\n      from db1.table4 as tab4"
      ],
      "fn": "from-sql",
      "ns": "op"
    }],
    "fn": "operators",
    "ns": "op"
  }
}
```

I want to extract the string `db1.table4` from this json file and store into a variable.

I don't know much about sed and awk. Can someone help here?

Comment: How can we know what to extract? Should it always be the second word from the first element in the the `args` array? Should it be whatever is after `select\n`? How can we identify the part of the file you want to extract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Assume that the string you want to extract stands in the same position in every file you can use `head`, `tail` and `cut` commands using pipes.
2. For example:

   ```
   $ head -6 file.json | tail -1 | cut -b 121-129
   db1.table
   ```
3. And here is an example of a script setting the output into a variable:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   v1=$(head -6 file.json | tail -1 | cut -b 121-130)
   echo "$v1"
   ```

The output of the script will be `db1.table4` which is the value of `V1` varaible.

You can read more about those commands here:

- [`head` command](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/head-command-linux-examples/)
- [`tail` command](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tail-command-linux-examples/)
- [`cut` command](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cut-command-linux-examples/)

Of course you can use those commands to extract any other string from a file.

Comment: thanks a lot. it helped me.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look [at `jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) the command line JSON processor, install for example with:

```
sudo apt install jq
```

The string you want is not a JSON value, it's part of a JSON value. So I suggest you use `jq` to get the string you need to manipulate into a variable, for example:

```
my_var=$(jq -r .[$quer].args[0].args[0] file1.json)
```

This gets you a variable containing the SELECT statement:

```
select db1.table1 as tab1, db1.table2 as tab2, db1.table3 as tab3 from db1.table4 as tab4
```

Then you will need to use other tools like sed, awk, cut etc to get the substring you want from that variable. For your specific case this would work but of course may not work for a different SELECT statement. Cutting by space delimiter and returning the 12th value:

```
my_table=$(echo $my_var | cut -d' ' -f12)
```

Comment: its already there but my question is not json related its to use the unix command.

Comment: @Aviator `jq` _is_ a command, just like any other. It is just the right tool to use when parsing json files.

Comment: Examples added above.

Comment: Thanks! That's much clearer :)

Answer (score 2):

You should generally avoid using generic text parsing tools for structured data. Since you have a json file, it is safer and simpler to use a dedicated json parser. In your case, you would want to extract the value of the first element of the array `args` which is itself the first element of the top level array `args`, the child of the top level hash `$quer`:

```
$ jq '."$quer"."args"[0]["args"]' file.json
[
  "select\n      db1.table1 as tab1,\n      db1.table2 as tab2,\n      db1.table3 as tab3\n      from db1.table4 as tab4"
]
```

From here, you no longer have structured data and you need to resort to cruder methods. I don't know how you want to identify your target string, you didn't explain that. So, depending on what you actually want, you could do:

1. Skip lines starting with `[` or `]` and then print the second word of the remaining lines:

   ```
   $ jq '."$quer"."args"[0]["args"]' file.json | awk '/^[^][]/{print $2}'
   db1.table1
   ```
2. Print the second word of the second line

   ```
   $ jq '."$quer"."args"[0]["args"]' file.json | awk 'NR==2{print $2}'
   db1.table1
   ```
3. Print the longest stretch of non-whitespace after the string `"select\n`:

   ```
   $ jq '."$quer"."args"[0]["args"]' file.json | grep -oP '"select\\n\s*\K\S*'
   db1.table1
   ```

If you explain exactly how we are supposed to know what string to extract, I could give you a more targeted answer.

---

For the sake of completion, in your *specific* example, and I stress that this will not be portable and is almost certain to fail if your input data change in any way, you can use simple text tools directly:

```
$ grep -oP '"select\\n\s*\K\S*' file.json 
db1.table1

$ awk '$1=="\"select\\n"{print $2}' file.json 
db1.table1

$ sed -nE 's/.*"select\\n\s*(\S+).*/\1/p' file.json 
db1.table1
```

Comment: You could possibly do some of the awk-like slicing'n'dicing in jq, for example `jq -r '."$quer".args[0].args[] | split("\n")[-1] | split(" ")[-3]' file.json` or maybe something regex based like `jq -r '."$quer".args[0].args[] | capture("from (?<a>[^ ]+)") | .a'`

Comment: @steeldriver yeah, but I figured that since I don't know what the OP actually wants to extract, I may as well give some simple choices.

Comment: indeed ... not clear