# How to grep the lines between the parent tags

Tags: command-line, text-processing, tomcat

```
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>DIGEST</auth-method>
    <realm-name>UserDatabase</realm-name>
  </login-config>
```

I need to grep the lines between `<login-config>` and `</login-config>`, can anyone suggest the best method

Comment: This looks like XML. Is it supposed to be XML?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract a string from a json file and put into a variable (Linux)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357926/how-to-extract-a-string-from-a-json-file-and-put-into-a-variable-linux)

Comment: `xmllint --xpath '//login-config/*' file.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Command

```
sed -n '/\<login-config/,/\/login-config/{//!p;}' file
```

will print the desired output, even for multiple matches of the opening/closing pattern.

Command

```
awk '/\<login-config/{f=1;next} /\/login-config/{f=0} f' file
```

works but only if there is only one match (it could surely be fixed).